# Can't delete a Page note via the Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-delete

I've been able to successfully create a Page 'Note' object via the Graph API, however can't seem to get the delete working.

I've been attempting to delete the note by issuing a HTTP DELETE to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[NOTE_ID]?access_token=[PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN]
```

Where:

- [NOTE_ID] is the 'story_fbid' of the page note
- [PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN] is the page-level access token

The error I get back from the Graph API is:
`{"error":{"message":"An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.","type":"OAuthException","code":2}}`

Noting that the documentation (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page) discusses creating page notes, but not deleting them. Perhaps this isn't possible ?

Comment: I have the exact same issue. Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I did formally raise a defect report with Facebook (http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/390562974332587?browse=search_5080f012a8f052c14504687) and while acknowledging the defect has been raised, they have marked it as 'low priority' and nothing has changed since.

Comment: Unfortunately Facebook closed my defect saying that they thought it was low-priority and no other customer seemed interested in fixing it ;( So if you experience this problem, then you will need to raise another defect with Facebook